# Discretise numbers in MS-EXCEL

Tags: excel

I need to do a set of data discretise in MS-EXCEL.
Mean, value in between 4.500 and 5.499  should be considered as 5, like this. I am not quiet sure this is call "Discretion".
Please feel free to suggest me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please make sure your question has mor info as stated in the rules.

Answer (score 1):

If you have data in Column A1, you can apply following formula in Column B1:

`=ROUND(A1,0)`